# why is the console saying something is wrong with my print " ".join(row) function?

Tags: python

```
import random

print "Welcome to my mastermind game. instead of colors, \
we will be using numbers, one through six \
(red is left, white is right)"

board = []
for x in range(0, 10):
    board.append(["O"]*4)

def mastermind_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

...
    mastermind_board(board)
turn + 1
```

The `print " ".join(row)` lines is where there is an issue, after submitting first item, it puts in the error (the dots are the extra code not important for the question)

Comment: It'd be useful if you could include the error you're getting...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with that code, I just tried it on machine. If you are using Python 3.3 you need to include parenthesis for print function. Try:

```
print(" ".join(row))
```

This is the output I get:

```
O O O O
O O O O
O O O O
O O O O
O O O O
O O O O
O O O O
O O O O
O O O O
O O O O
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're trying to use .join() on individual rows: you could apply it to the entire array and it should work fine.

(You'd have to change the format of the the appended "O"s to make it look the way you intend, though)